# How do I have a fixed right aligned container and use the parent to scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup:

- Full width, 100px height `header`

  - Header is always visible at the top.
- Full width, remaining height `details`

  - Content of `details` can scroll vertically and horizontally
  - A fixed 200px width, full height container is right aligned to the `details`.
  - The detail container controls the scrolling and there is padding on the right to account for the right aligned frozen section.

The body of the page does not scroll at all, only the `details` container.

---

This is how I want it to look: https://jsbin.com/mowojix/5/edit?html,css,output.  However, once you scroll, you notice the right aligned container is just set in place and moves with the scroll.  Here I have the right aligned container inside the scrollable container to keep it inside the scrollbars.

---

This is how I want it to function: https://jsbin.com/mowojix/7/edit?html,css,output.  However, notice the right container is sitting above the scrollbars.  Here I have the right aligned container outside the scrollable container so it can actually stay floating on the right.

---

I think I am missing something easy here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is what you were looking for. Still relying on the browser scrollbar and fixing the header and side elements though.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100px;
  width:100vw;
  background:red;
}

.main {
  margin-top:100px;
  background:lightblue;
  max-height:calc(100vh - 100px);
  max-width:100vw;
}

.main-content {
  width:200vw;
  height:200vh;
  background:blue;
}

.side {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:100px;
  background:green;
  width:200px;
  height:60vh;
}
```

```html
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        Header
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        <section class="main-content">Main content area</section>
        <section class="side">Side</section>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Ah, sorry for being unclear, but this is not what I am looking for.  I need an element that is fixed to the right side of a container, not the page.

Comment: @bunkscene Divide your container into another div whatever size you want it in your page and add the above solution if it is still correct inside your container.

Comment: @Mugé Position: fixed is only relative to the page.  There is a hack you can add using `transform` to change the viewport, but it still doesn't work as desired.